# "comigo o buraco é mais embaixo". Que buraco?

Tags: ditados, expressões-populares

Quem nunca ouviu alguém dizer "comigo o buraco é mais embaixo"?  Acredito que seja uma expressão popular bem antiga, mas que ainda ouvimos com relativa frequência. Em contexto, o significado é muito fácil de entender e significa "comigo as coisas são diferentes" ou "comigo as coisas não funcionam assim".  No entanto, nunca me perguntei que buraco seria esse e também nunca ouvi ninguém explicar. Pergunto aqui então:

- O buraco em questão é referente a algum orifício corporal?
- Quando e onde surgiu tal expressão?  Foi trazida para o Brasil colônia?

EDIT - Àqueles que estão aprendendo a língua portuguesa, vale a pena informar que não se trata de uma expressão a ser usada em "círculos educados".  Quanto a ser agressiva ou não, depende do contexto: comentar com um amigo "O João não sabe que comigo o buraco é mais embaixo", não transmite nenhuma agressividade.  Mas, se dita com tom ameaçador tal como "ó gajo, tu tomas cuidado. Comigo o buraco é mais embaixo, tá?", é realmente uma frase agressiva.

Comment: A construção é muito usada em outro contexto, mais impessoal. Por exemplo, *ganhar do Madureira no Maracanã é fácil, em Conselheiro Galvão o buraco é mais embaixo*; *sua tese é perfeita no que toca ao capitalismo concorrencial; no capitalismo monopolista, o buraco é mais embaixo*; *ontem foi prova de Geografia; hoje é Física, o buraco é mais embaixo*. Quanto a qual a origem da expressão, bem... aí o buraco é mais embaixo.

Comment: @LuísHenrique   Good call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consultando [*o Dicionário inFormal*](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/o%20buraco%20%C3%A9%20mais%20em%20baixo/), o buraco seria a cova onde a pessoa seria enterrada. No meu entender, seria mais difícil *terminar comigo*.

Answer (score 0):

A origem é de uma piada muito popular que ouvi no final dos anos 70 no Brasil. Depois comecei a ouvir a expressão. Era mais ou menos assim:
Os presidentes dos Estados Unidos, Brasil e o premier da União Soviética, estavam esperando numa sala antes de uma reunião de cúpula.
O russo, querendo contar vantagem com o americano, diz:
-“No meu país fizemos um avião que chega ao espaço!”
-“Ao espaço?! Perguntam os outros dois, com um ar de incredulidade.
-“Bem, quase… como um palmo abaixo.”
O americano, para não ficar pra trás, diz:
-“Ora, isso não é nada! No meu país temos uns atletas que saltam na altura da Estátua da liberdade!”
Os dois o olham com desconfiança, então ele corrige:
-“Bem, quase. Um palmo abaixo.”
O Brasileiro, para não ficar pra atrás, diz:
-“Ora, no Brasil as mulheres têm filho pelo umbigo!… ***Bem, um palmo abaixo!***”

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas por favor note que geralmente se esperam respostas bem fundamentadas — por exemplo com referências. Você tem alguma fonte que confirme sua resposta?